M series Mac - TestFlight does not show Install option for iPad app on MxMac
Our users install our iPad app on their M-Series macs from AppStore. But, when I make the TestFlight app, I was expecting TestFlight would show Install button for iPad app too so that I can test the app on M1 mac. But it doesn't.
Still, it shows it requires M1 mac, well, I am on M1 Mac. Our testers are on M1 mac. Still, no button to install.
Can someone throw hints please?

